# Gnustep with Cmake

Tags: objective-c, cmake, gnustep

I am  currently trying to use objective-c with cmake and GNUStep and managed to enable objective c in cmake using mingw compiler but i wanted to know how to use gnustep with cmake so  i could program in objective c on windows or linux so how could i do this is there any ideas or cmake script?
My mainly goal is compiling objc code from cmake directly without using gnumake files or the shell

I tried  linking gnustep from it's folder which installed but it didn't work and i searched for any cmake script to link gnustep directly from it's installed folder in c drive and also nothing came up
I am using vs code on windows along side with mingw gcc compiler